# Get Chat (Empathy) to pop up when people are talking to me

Tags: empathy

When people start a new convo with me, all I see initially is that the message indicator is lit. This isn't quite obvious, so I'd like the new chat window to just pop up in my face. How can I do this?

Comment: I'd suggest not doing that as it will be distracting when not running a full screen application. For example you are writing a document or playing a game, and a chat window pops up grabbing your attention *and* the controls to your annoyance.

Comment: It's not distracting if your window manager is configured to make new windows less obtrusive.  Mine is set up to place new chat windows in a background workspace and to set the urgent hint.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Edit ➜ Preferences ➜ General ➜ Behavior ➜ Uncheck **Display incoming events in notification area***.

[image]

The Messaging Menu indicator will no longer change color/brightness when you someone tries to talk to you, but that shouldn't be needed because the window will open automatically.

Comment: I would NEVER suspect this checkbox to work this way.

Comment: With Empathy 3.8.6 running on Ubuntu 14.04 this solution does not work anymore. The only "Behavior" option left to me it whether to auto connect on startup :-(