# Make a new chat window open when someone contacts me

Tags: 12.10, empathy

I'd like it that when I receive a new IM, empathy launches an IM window (if one isn't already open). Is there any way to do this? I would like this to happen for two reasons:

1. Currently, when someone IM's me, a popup appears, which I often miss. A more permanent window would be more noticeable.
2. I don't want to have to navigate the mail dropdown menu to get to the chat. Its rather inconvenient. Similarly, clicking on the empathy launcher doesn't bring you to the new chat (despite it indicating there is a new chat). Having a new window pop up would be the most convenient way to quickly start talking.

Comment: Have you seen http://askubuntu.com/questions/22292/get-chat-empathy-to-pop-up-when-people-are-talking-to-me ? I *think* that will do the trick ;)